# QThread and implementation of notify

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qapplication

What to look out for when reimplementing `notify` function in multi threaded Qt application?
This is an example implementation. **Currently there are no errors**, but I am worried that an error could arise since multi threading in Qt uses signal slot for communication which uses notify function.

```
TApplication::notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event)
{
    bool returnValue(false);
    try
    {
        returnValue = QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
    }
    catch (IExceptionBase& e)
    {
        if (!fMain.isNull())
        {
            //report error to output and file log
        }
        else
        {
            //report error to output
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        if (!fMain.isNull())
        {
            //report error to output and file log
        }
        else
        {
            //report error to output
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

`fMain` is a module with reporting functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt5, this is safe. However, [from the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#notify), in Qt6 this will no longer work outside the main thread, and in fact, the function is being considered for deprecation in Qt6 entirely.

As Kuba Ober pointed out, reimplementing `notify` to catch exceptions is a bad idea, as events in other threads and any queued signals are delivered asynchronously.

Comment: Reimplementation of `notify` was done to implement a blanket "catch-all" exception sink. `postEvent` won't have anything to do with that, because the event handler doesn't execute from within it.

Comment: @KubaOber: Doh. The lack of a function signature and the code indentation confused me regarding the author's actual (versus stated) purpose. I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Catching all exceptions in `notify` is an anti-pattern. It used to be cool to do, but turned out to be a bad idea. So don't do that. If your slots or event handlers throw, wrap their code in a `try-catch` block. `notify` gives you a false sense of security because in very many cases, signals and directly-connected slots happen to be called from event handlers. But sometimes that won't be the case, and your code will crash due to an unhandled exception.

Make sure you're familiar with the [Core C++ Error Handling Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-errors) and [C++ Exceptions and Error Handling FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions).

Comment: I'm going all in and reinforcing this idea: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/162682/3/src/corelib/kernel/qeventloop.cpp

Comment: @peppe, so it's not an anti pattern to catch all exception in notify in qt5 if I use something like deleteLater, right? Then is it only way to catch exception instead of event handler?

Comment: @user150497 It's not about `deleteLater` or anything else. *Don't let exceptions leave slots and event handlers.* As far as I'm concerned, Qt should detect this and fail an assertion in debug mode if that sort of abuse is perpetuated (not merely issue a warning).